# Вычислить размер ограничивающего прямоугольника повернутой произвольной фигуры, не прямоугольника

Tags: java, android, kotlin, геометрия

Никак не могу найти формулу для такого расчета.
Есть фигура определенной ширины и высоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого поворачиваю фигуру, например, на 30 градусов программно, язык не особо важен, формула, если есть, то будет одинаковая для любого языка, но именно сейчас делаю для java или kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли формула, чтобы вычислить новые ширину и высоту, зная ширину и высоту без поворота и угол поворота?

Нашел статью для прямоугольника
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971230/calculate-rotated-rectangle-size-from-known-bounding-box-coordinates
Но в случае с прямоугольником на экране выглядит нормально только, когда поворачиваешь на 90, 180, 270, 360 при других градусах слишком большой отступ получается.

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь что такая формула возможна для произвольной фигуры

Comment: не зная самой фигуры вы не сможете посчитать ограничивающий прямоугольник после поворота. Мы можете тоько повернуть изначальный прямоугольник и посчитать по нему, но это будет неточный прямоугольник.

Answer (score 0):

Все предельно просто. Это не возможно не зная самой фигуры.

Возьмите квадрат за одну фигуру а вторую его диагональ или что нибудь близкое к нему. Начинайте вращять, согласно вашим предположениям формула должна дать одинаковый ответ для обоих случаев при любом повороте. Думаю достаточно посмотреть на угол в 45 градусов чтобы понять что формула не верна.

А что действительно нужно делать каждый раз при повороте это вычислять min и max по координатно из множества точек фигуры чтобы определить прямоугольник ограничивающий эту произвольную фигуру. И чем точнее задана фигура, тем точнее будет ваш расчет.